# Camel file component : create a file and if already exist, move it and renamed it with timestamp

Tags: java, file, apache-camel

I'm using Camel 2.17 and I would like to produce a file.
If the file already exist, I want to move existing file in another folder and add a timestamp to the moved file.

Here is the code I use :

```
from("activemq:queue:MYQUEUE")
.toD("file:/opt/data/out?"
 + "fileName=toto.txt"
 + "&fileExist=Move"
 + "&moveExisting=issue/${date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss_}${file:onlyname}");
```

**expected behaviour** :
File created at : `/opt/data/out/issue/20190226_162001_toto.txt`

**obtained behaviour** :
File created at : `/opt/data/out/issue/20190226_163226_\toto.txt`
a sub directory `20190226_163226_` is created.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Try with `issue/${date:now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}_${file:onlyname}`

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen, solution you propose is not OK, as you can see below the issue is coming from the `.toD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it may be a little issue/bug with the `toD` and the file component in this situation. However you should *not* use toD in this use-case as the file component already support this with *to*. As the `moveExisting` option accepts the simple expression and has special support for it.

**Update:** Okay so its actually as designed, because you are using `toD` then the endpoint moveExisting gets evaluated first, and then when the file producer reads this value, its seen as a static value, which by default will automatic assume its a folder name (this is how these options work), and therefore create it as a folder instead of the final file name.

Comment: I logged a ticket to see if we can improve/fix this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13272

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to my issue :

just replace the `.toD("file")` by `.to("file")`
It's now OK